# Program to print Sierpinski triangle

Tags: java, c, algorithm, scala, logic

i was just looking Wikipedia pages and i found this [Sierpinski triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_triangle)

i want to create this  triangle by `java`,`c`,`scala` etc.

```
                               1                               
                              111                              
                             11111                             
                            1111111                            
                           111111111                           
                          11111111111                          
                         1111111111111                         
                        111111111111111                        
                       1               1                       
                      111             111                      
                     11111           11111                     
                    1111111         1111111                    
                   111111111       111111111                   
                  11111111111     11111111111                  
                 1111111111111   1111111111111                 
                111111111111111 111111111111111                
               1                               1               
              111                             111              
             11111                           11111             
            1111111                         1111111            
           111111111                       111111111           
          11111111111                     11111111111          
         1111111111111                   1111111111111         
        111111111111111                 111111111111111        
       1               1               1               1       
      111             111             111             111      
     11111           11111           11111           11111     
    1111111         1111111         1111111         1111111    
   111111111       111111111       111111111       111111111   
  11111111111     11111111111     11111111111     11111111111  
 1111111111111   1111111111111   1111111111111   1111111111111 
111111111111111 111111111111111 111111111111111 111111111111111
```

i just create simple program like we create simple pattern in `c`  i wrote this in `scala`

```
def ft(n: Int) = {
    for (i <- 1 to n) {
      for (j <- n to i by -1) {
        print(" ")
      }
      for (k <- 1 to 2 * i - 1) {
        print("1")

      }
      print("\n")
    }
  }
```

to print  this

```
           1
          111
         11111
        1111111
       111111111
```

and this :

```
def triangle = {
    for (i <- 1 to 5) {
      for (j <- 1 to 5) {
        if (j <= i)
          print("1")
        else
          print(" ")
      }
      for (j <- 5 to 1 by -1) {
        if (j <= i)
          print("1");
        else
          print(" ");
      }
      print("\n");
    }
  }
```

how to create this **Sierpinski triangle** ?

just give me idea to solve this ?

Comment: You have tagged 5 languages. In which language do you want the solution?

Comment: i am just looking for `logic` to solve this triangle. You can provide in any language

Comment: The logic is to use recursion. Each triangle can be split into four smaller ones. Leave the middle one blank and call yourself recursively on the other three. At some arbitrary point stop the recursion and use your routine to draw normal triangles.

Comment: @RahulKulhari: The tools you use do tend to _"colour"_ the approach you use to solve this problem. Java, for example, is an OO-only language, C is anything but OO. Solving this in Scheme/lisp will be an all-function-effort, as will JavaScript, whereas using Perl will yield code-golfing style answers...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Scala or Java, but it seems that the language doesn't matter to you. Here's a solution in PostScript:

```
%PS-Adobe 3.0

/Sierp {    % x1 y1 x2 y1 x3 y3 depth
    13 dict begin
        /D exch def
        /Y3 exch def
        /X3 exch def
        /Y2 exch def
        /X2 exch def
        /Y1 exch def
        /X1 exch def

        D 0 le {
            newpath
            X1 Y1 moveto
            X2 Y2 lineto
            X3 Y3 lineto
            fill
        } {
            /X12 X1 X2 add 0.5 mul def
            /Y12 Y1 Y2 add 0.5 mul def
            /X23 X2 X3 add 0.5 mul def
            /Y23 Y2 Y3 add 0.5 mul def
            /X31 X3 X1 add 0.5 mul def
            /Y31 Y3 Y1 add 0.5 mul def

            X1 Y1 X12 Y12 X31 Y31 D 1 sub Sierp
            X12 Y12 X2 Y2 X23 Y23 D 1 sub Sierp
            X31 Y31 X23 Y23 X3 Y3 D 1 sub Sierp
        } ifelse

    end
} bind def

/Sierpinski {   % xc yc radius depth
    4 dict begin
        /D exch def
        /R exch def
        /Y exch def
        /X exch def

        X
        Y R add
        X 0.8333 R mul add
        Y -0.5 R mul add
        X -0.8333 R mul add
        Y -0.5 R mul add
        D
        Sierp
    end
} bind def

300 400 250 6 Sierpinski
showpage
```

Answer (score 1):

I have written Sierpinski triangle program in JavaScript. This JavaScript code runs in Chrome.

[Sierpinski triangle](http://jsfiddle.net/mzilenas/n99x3/embedded/result/) . To see the code click in the upper right side a link "edit in JsFiddle". The idea here is to generate data then draw circles for each number.

```
function Triangle() {}

Triangle.prototype.height = function () {
    return this.data.length;
}

Triangle.prototype.scale = function scale(ctx, height) {
    ballsfits = this.canvas.width / 2;
    ballsgot = height;
    var scale = ballsfits / ballsgot;
    ctx.scale(scale, scale);
    return scale;
}

Triangle.prototype.init = function () {
    this.canvas = gCanvas();
    var ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.canvas.width = this.canvas.width; //clear
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
    return ctx;
}

Triangle.prototype.generate = function (height) {
    //init
    this.data = new Array();
    this.data.push([1]);
    this.data.push(new Array(1, 1));

    for (var i = 2; i < height; i++) {
        var cRow = [1];
        // add each two members of preceeding row
        for (var j = 0; j < this.data[i - 1].length - 1; j++)
        cRow.push((this.data[i - 1][j] + this.data[i - 1][j + 1]) % 2);
        cRow.push(1);
        this.data.push(cRow);
    }
}

Triangle.prototype.draw = function () {
    var h = this.height();
    var ctx = this.init();
    var scale = this.scale(ctx, h);
    for (var y = 0; y < h; y++)
    for (var x = 0; x < this.data[y].length; x++)
    if (0 != this.data[y][x]) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(h - this.data[y].length + x * 2 + 1, y * 2 + 1, 1, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fill();
    }
}
```

The code doesn't use big numbers. The only needed information is whether the number is divisible by 2. So 0, 1 and are used:

```
(this.data[i - 1][j] + this.data[i - 1][j + 1]) % 2
```

This **reduces computation time**.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this by structuring the index in a clever way involving a power of 2 somewhere as expected but as always python has one of the cleanest representation albeit somewhat backward

```
def sierpinski(n):    
  d = ["*"]    
  for i in xrange(n):        
    sp = " " * (2 ** i)        
    d = [sp+x+sp for x in d] + [x+" "+x for x in d]    
return d 

print "\n".join(sierpinski(4))
```

The trick is to realize it's not printing the * that makes up the triangle but all the spaces as well, change " " in the code to "c" and you will see the following.  Idea is it starts with a basic pattern and keeps appending to its head and tail so you start with 2 elements, then 4, then 8, finally 16.  and since python prints list with newline delimiters you naturally get the pattern you are looking for.

```
sp is c
['c*c', '*c*']


sp is cc
['ccc*ccc', 'cc*c*cc', 'c*ccc*c', '*c*c*c*']


sp is cccc
['ccccccc*ccccccc', 'cccccc*c*cccccc', 'ccccc*ccc*ccccc', 'cccc*c*c*c*cccc', 'ccc*ccccccc*ccc', 'cc*c*ccccc*c*cc', 'c*ccc*ccc*ccc*c', '*c*c*c*c*c*c*c*']


sp is cccccccc
['ccccccccccccccc*ccccccccccccccc', 'cccccccccccccc*c*cccccccccccccc', 'ccccccccccccc*ccc*ccccccccccccc', 'cccccccccccc*c*c*c*cccccccccccc', 'ccccccccccc*ccccccc*ccccccccccc', 'cccccccccc*c*ccccc*c*cccccccccc', 'ccccccccc*ccc*ccc*ccc*ccccccccc', 'cccccccc*c*c*c*c*c*c*c*cccccccc', 'ccccccc*ccccccccccccccc*ccccccc', 'cccccc*c*ccccccccccccc*c*cccccc', 'ccccc*ccc*ccccccccccc*ccc*ccccc', 'cccc*c*c*c*ccccccccc*c*c*c*cccc', 'ccc*ccccccc*ccccccc*ccccccc*ccc', 'cc*c*ccccc*c*ccccc*c*ccccc*c*cc', 'c*ccc*ccc*ccc*ccc*ccc*ccc*ccc*c', '*c*c*c*c*c*c*c*c*c*c*c*c*c*c*c*']


ccccccccccccccc*ccccccccccccccc
cccccccccccccc*c*cccccccccccccc
ccccccccccccc*ccc*ccccccccccccc
cccccccccccc*c*c*c*cccccccccccc
ccccccccccc*ccccccc*ccccccccccc
cccccccccc*c*ccccc*c*cccccccccc
ccccccccc*ccc*ccc*ccc*ccccccccc
cccccccc*c*c*c*c*c*c*c*cccccccc
ccccccc*ccccccccccccccc*ccccccc
cccccc*c*ccccccccccccc*c*cccccc
ccccc*ccc*ccccccccccc*ccc*ccccc
cccc*c*c*c*ccccccccc*c*c*c*cccc
ccc*ccccccc*ccccccc*ccccccc*ccc
cc*c*ccccc*c*ccccc*c*ccccc*c*cc
c*ccc*ccc*ccc*ccc*ccc*ccc*ccc*c
*c*c*c*c*c*c*c*c*c*c*c*c*c*c*c*
```